# What's wrong with std::unique_copy (or my use of it)?

Tags: c++, stl, standard-library, std

I have roughly the following code that is supposed to collect unique segment indices into `uniques`:

```
    vector< int > segments;
    // segments vector is filled in here
    // ...
    sort( segments.begin(), segments.end() );
    vector< int > uniques;
    uniques.reserve( segments.size() );
#ifdef USE_STD_UNIQUE_COPY
    unique_copy( segments.begin(), segments.end(), uniques.begin() );
#else
    if( segments.size() > 0 )
        uniques.push_back( segments[ 0 ] );
    for( size_t i = 1; i < segments.size(); ++i)
    {
        if( segments[ i ] != uniques.back() )
            uniques.push_back( segments[ i ] );
    }
#endif
```

When `USE_STD_UNIQUE_COPY` is defined the code fails; when it's undefined it works as expected. The whole piece runs on multiple threads, and I didn't debug yet how exactly `std::unique_copy` output differs. Regardless, according to cppreference `std::unique_copy (1)` should do exactly what the `#else` part of the code does.

Thus the question: what's wrong in this picture? Does `std::unique_copy` has limitation, maybe not thread-safe? Or maybe I'm misreading cppreference and using it incorrectly?

Comment: `s/uniques.begin()/back_inserter(uniques)/`

Comment: `reserve` != `resize`. so your `unique_copy` is wrong, or you should use `back_inserter`

Comment: The third parameter must be an `output_iterator`.

Comment: @Arunmu are you implying that vector's `random_access_iterator` is not `output_iterator`?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Yes, For a function which expects an output_iterator, we cannot pass it an input/forward/random access iterator.

Comment: @Arunmu You can't?  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cff3ac18bd39ec4

Comment: @NathanOliver I was talking (in response to Revolver) in general context that when a function expects an `output_iterator_tag` we cannot pass it an `randomaccess_iterator`. For unique_copy its working because I guess it has overloads for both `input_iterator_tag` and `forward_iterator_tag`.

Comment: @Arunmu no algorithms use iterator tags in any way. `OutputIterator` refers to concept which all standard library container iterators satisfy.

Comment: @Arunmu That is not the problem.  The only thing it requires is write access.  non const random access iterators give you that.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot They do. Thats how they provide efficient versions of the algorithm. Eg: `std::reverse` for list and vector.

Comment: @NathanOliver Understood. Thanks. Maybe I was taking the discussion in a different way.

Comment: @Arunmu I get what you are saying it is just not the case here.  They are just template names here to try and enforce a concept.  There are no tags or hard requirements per the standard.  As long as the container has the space any iterator works.  If it does not have the space then you need something like `back_inserter` that will create it for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree 100% with you :). It was wrong from my side to discuss something not related to this question here. I stopped being relevant to this question from my first response comment to 'Revolver' :)

Comment: @T.C.: thanks, with `back_inserter` it works as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to copy to an invalid destination range. Essentially, your call to reserve allocates the space the vector needs, but does not actually change its size. So you can't directly copy to its elements. Your alternative code works because calls to push_back expand the vector size by 1 and append to the end.

As has already been indicated in the comments, there is a clever way to use unique_copy anyway. You change it to use a back_inserter for the destination range.

```
unique_copy(segments.begin(), segments.end(), back_inserter(uniques));
```

The back_inserter creates a back_insert_iterator which, when copied to, calls push_back on the container.